A question about combinatorics and probability density function
$n$ students from the University $A$ and $n$ students from University $B$ are timed for how fast they can run $1$ kilometer. The students are
ranked from $1$ (fastest) to $2n$ (slowest). There are no ties and in advance of the results every
rank is equally likely for every one of the students. What is the distribution of top finishing
ranks for the students in University $A$, i.e. what is the probability mass function $T(i)$ giving the
probability that the fastest University $A$ student finished in place $i, i =1,2,\cdots,n+1$.
My idea is that if the fastest University $A$ student finished in place $i$, then the fastest
$(i-1)$ students from University $B$ should take up the first $i-1$ spots, which means the first $i$ spots has only one arrangement.
And the remaining $(2n-i)$ students (from $A$ and $B$) will take up the remaining $(2n-i)$ spots.
Therefore
$$
T(i)=\frac{(2n-i)!}{(2n)!}.
$$
Is my understanding correct? Any help will be appreciated.

Your solution would have $T(1)$ (probability that a runner from University A finishes first) being $\frac{1}{2N}$. But that probability should be $\frac12$. I think your solution sometimes treats all runners from a given university as indistinguishable, and sometimes as distinguishable. This leads to inconsistencies.
Let's try to solve the problem treating students from either given university as indistinguishable. Let $a$ represent a (generic) student from University A, and similarly for $b$ and University B.
As you note there is only one arrangement of $a$'s and $b$'s for the first $i$ slots. However, the last $2N-i$ slots, must be filled with $N-1$ $a$'s and $N-i+1$ $b$'s in any order. This can be done in ${{2N-i}\choose{N-1}}$ ways.
Hence the desired probability is
$$T(i)=\frac{{{2N-i}\choose{N-1}}}{{{2N}\choose{N}}}$$

This is more proper. Thank you very much.
